# "zip I/O error: Permission denied" with exec command

Tags: php, zip, exec

I'm trying to recursively zip a directory with the `exec` command, first of all I do not need the `zipArchive` class for outline reasons however when I pass this command in the `exec` command I get an error saying:

> zip I/O error: Permission denied

For this command:

```
cd ../../; zip -P temppassword html/acp/backup/filename.zip -r html/ 2>&1
```

It starts out in the script located `/var/www/html/acp/config.php` and it will move to the `www` directory after `cd ../../`, then zip up the `html` directory and store the zip file into `/var/www/html/acp/backup/` directory. But unfortunately I get a permission error. How can I allow the command to pass through with "permission"?

Comment: Why is this marked off-topic for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could be either:

1. The web server user ID doesn't have permission to write out the .zip you're generating
2. The web server user ID doesn't have permission to read a file/directory somewhere in the area you're zipping up.

Comment: So I assume the user is `apache`. How can I allow the user to have permissions to do so?

Comment: in a horribly hacky way: `chown -R apache:apache html/` or `chmod -R 777 html/`. Preferably you should figure out which directory/file is/are causing the error and fix up those only.

Comment: Ah yes, I just chmodded the backup directory, that must have been why it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: If you CHMOD the backup directory, aren't you allowing write access to that directory to the world (users who can call the script)?

Comment: @horatio: yes, but it'd only be an issue if users could get AT that directory in the first place, e.g. on shared hosting or a script that allows arbitrary uploads

Comment: I thought as much. The OP said `/var/www/html/acp/backup/` which I assumed is shared.